# Machine.Specifications.MVC ShouldBeAView() always fails even on valid ViewResults

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mspec

Has anyone run into this while using Machine.Specifications.Mvc?

I setup a spec to test the results of a controller action. In this case:

```
[Subject("User views the dashboard")]
public class When_a_user_views_the_vendors_page
     : ManagementContext
{
    static ActionResult result;

    Because of = () => result = manageController.Vendors();

    It should_contain_a_list_of_vendors = () => {

        result.ShouldBeAView().And().ShouldHaveModelOfType<List<Core.Vendor>>();
    };
}
```

The error I get every time is:

> Machine.Specifications.SpecificationException: Should be of type System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult but is of type System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult
>      at Machine.Specifications.ShouldExtensionMethods.ShouldBeOfType(Object actual, Type expected) in d:\BuildAgent-01\work\340c36596c29db8\Source\Machine.Specifications\ExtensionMethods.cs:line 206

Has anyone seen this?  Is there an easy way to resolve it?  It seems to be happening in the Machine.Specifications library.  I even ran it in a debug mode to check the values and they are indeed both ViewResult objects and with the correct model data even.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay... Silly problem. (I knew it would be).   I've recently begun experimenting with MVC2.  Machine.Specifications.Mvc out of the box is wired to 1.0;

I re-referenced Machine.Specifications.Mvc to Mvc2, and it worked like a charm.

doh! :)